# PayPal removes the query string values in the Notify URL that is used for IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Starting from this week, PayPal seems to be removing the query string values in the notify_url that is sent in the request.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?token=example&pskey=test&order_id=100045
```

This becomes

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?token=example
```

Only the first key-pair is kept while the remaining are removed.

And this does not happen for every request. About 40% of the requests go through ok, when the remaining have problems.

As a result, there are problems in confirming the orders. We will have to manually confirm the orders

Comment: It's still a problem - see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696341/paypal-removes-the-query-string-values-in-the-notify-url-that-is-used-for-ipn

Comment: While this isn't an answer I don't have enough SO privs to comment and I wanted to offer support that this issue does exist and is increasing in frequency, OP is not alone. At 23:59 last night we started to hit this issue for 100% of our orders, none of which returned the value for query params.
Our url is in the form `/ipn.php?order_id=123456` where Paypal started to return `/ipn.php?order_id`, therefore our IPN didn't have any clue as to what the Order was. Further to this Paypal omits all other useful info in the response and we're left with manually processing some of our orders, after som